# What's the best way to skip an Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm developing an app in which a user logs in to his dashboard and stays logged in until he logs out (I mean if the app is closed and restarted, he still stays logged in). I'm using `SharedPreferences` to check if the user is actually logged in.

**Preference.java**

```
public class Preference {

    Context context;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    public Preference(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("LoginState", 0);
    }

    public boolean getIsLoggedIn(){
        return sharedPref.getBoolean("State", false);
    }

    public void setIsLoggedIn(boolean state){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("State", state);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

I call the function `setIsLoggedIn(true)` when the user logs in and `setIsLoggedIn(false)` when the user logs out. But how to check and skip the LoginActivity if the user is already logged in?

Comment: That is actually my earlier question. I've implemented the SharedPreferences correctly but I don't know an effective way to skip the Login activity

Comment: On Splash Activity get value from shared preference if it is true then call next activity rather then login, if it is false then only call Login activity

Comment: U can make condition start activity from ur splash screen

Comment: So, I need an activity before the login activity which coordinates which Activity to show next?

Comment: its clean and easy approach to handle ur scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this condition in your Splash screen

```
Preference pre = new Preference(SplashScreen.this);
    if(preference.getIsLoggedIn()){
    // move to Login Screen
    }else{
     // move to your mainscreen
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was looking for method without the splash screen. But, if it works, it should be alright I guess

Answer (score 0):

If `LoginActivity` is default app activity called by launcher icon you can simply check login on it's `onCreate()` method and show another activity if user logged in.

```
onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Preference p = new Preference(this);
    if(p.getIsLoggedIn()) {
       finish();
       // start another app activity here ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your first Activity do this

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();               
    Boolean flag = sharedPref.getBoolean("state", false);
                    if(flag==false){
    // Start your login ACTIVITY
                    }else{
                        //Start your activity which you want to hit after login
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add some code to your LoginActivity's onResume or onCreate method,
that checks, if the user is logged in, and if so fire an intent that starts the Dashboard Activity.
Something like this.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Preferences.getIsLoggedIn()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class));
    }
}
```